# Are these boost shared pointer initializations in PCL different?

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr, point-cloud-library

I've been using PCL for a while now and seen several ways to initialize a `boost::shared_ptr`. Here are the examples I'm considering:

- `pointCloudType::Ptr cloud (new pointCloudType);`
- `pointCloudType::Ptr cloud = pointCloudType::Ptr(new pointCloudType);`
- `pointCloudType::Ptr cloud = pointCloudType::Ptr(new pointCloudType());`

Is there any difference between them and/or advantage of using one over the others?

Comment: Examples 2 and 3 are identical. Example 1 should be preferred as it is shorted and does not involve call to copy-constructor.

Comment: @taketwo Thanks, so I guess that Example 1 is more efficient than the others. What about when a pointer has been declared but not initialized? Can you still apply method 1? i.e. `pointCloudType::Ptr cloud;` and afterwards do `cloud(new pointCloudType);`?

Comment: In this case you should use `cloud.reset(new pointCloudType);`

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @taketwo I got this answer:

> Examples 2 and 3 are identical. Example 1 should be preferred as it is shorted and does not involve call to copy-constructor.

As example 1 should be preferred, when a pointer has been declared but not initialized, the way to go is

```
cloud.reset(new pointCloudType);
```